# Why does matplotlib / seaborn only take long format and not wide format?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Current Format:

```
YEAR      A       B      C 
2010    0.98    0.17    0.09
2011    0.11    1.00    0.37
2012    0.77    0.29    0.96
2013    0.51    0.93    0.40
2014    0.03    0.61    0.26
2015    0.42    0.55    0.92
```

Seaborn, from my understanding expects:

```
A   2010    0.98
A   2011    0.11
A   2012    0.77
A   2013    0.51
A   2014    0.03
A   2015    0.42
B   2010    0.17
B   2011    1.00
B   2012    0.29
B   2013    0.93
B   2014    0.61
B   2015    0.55
```

I understand we can convert easily, but someone asked me this question. Given even excel accept both formats, why does visualization libraries are restricted to rather unfriendly long format?

Comment: I don't think one can say that visualization libraries are in general restricted to long form data. It totally depends on what you want to do. But in order to use some of seaborn's features a long form dataset is required indeed. That is a design choice; but if you ask me, it's a reasonable one. The long form format allows to have one graphical feature per column of data without interpreting a matrix-like view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For seaborn, I think the philosophy is can be seen [in this statement in introduction](https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html) :

> Notice how we only provided the names of the variables in the dataset and the roles that we wanted them to play in the plot.
>   Unlike when using matplotlib directly, it wasn’t necessary to translate the variables into parameters of the visualization (e.g., the specific color or marker to use for each category).
>   That translation was done automatically by seaborn. This lets the user stay focused on the question they want the plot to answer.

I understand it this way : The idea is to focus on features names and their relations. Most of the time, users rely on Pandas for building the data matrix, which incites you to give column names, i.e. features names.
It is maybe easier for most people to perform treatment on the A column with numpy or pandas. That is not a fact, just my today’a feeling about it.

Or maybe most of us grew up with Excel...

Edit : now I realize I’m just repeating ImportanceOfBeingErnest’s comment ...